# Linux driver resource protection

Tags: linux, device-driver

I'm writing a Linux device driver and am pretty new at this so I'm learning quickly how NOT to do things. I'm currently using a couple of mutexes to prevent some functions from concurrently reading from the device and running into deadlocks on resume from suspend. My problem is two-fold:

1) Interrupt handler schedules a workqueue to read from the FIFO of the device and process data. FIFO needs to be read uninterrupted by other reads so I have placed a mutex (A) lock/unlock in the read, write functions.

2) Device configuration function is a sequence of read and writes using the same read, write functions as above that must be done uninterrupted by other reads or writes so I have placed a mutex (B) lock/unlock in the config functions. Device configuration functions are called by SYSFS nodes.

The issue appears to be when the system resumes from suspend, an interrupt triggers the FIFO call and at near the same time higher layers write to the SYSFS nodes to set configuration parameters and the system seems to deadlock during configuration sequence. Is my issue just that I'm using mutex which sleeps where I should be using a spinlock? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Hi - I'm not sure of the specific problem, but these two links might help: [Kernel APIs, Part 2: Deferrable functions, kernel tasklets, and work queues: An introduction to bottom halves](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-tasklets/), and [Top and Bottom Halves](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-10-sect-4)

Answer (score 0):

1. Get an interrupt.
2. Ack/disable interrupt in interrupt handler.
3. Start work queue.
4. Do high-priority processing, like get data off device and onto queue.
5. Enable device interrupt and go process lower-priority data in work queue.

Two difference mutexes here can't work because the locking order may be A->B [where try to acquire mutex B while holding mutex A] while another path is B->A which is textbook deadly embrace.

The solution is to re-structure your processing in to high-priority work (very limited task) to give data to the lower-priority work.

If the test for busy/availableis more than just a yes/no test, use a condition variable to guard the complex testing must be done.